# Class Method missing one positional argument

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have defined the following parent class:

```
class Material(object):
    def newMaterial(self,matPhysLaw, stressState,e,nu,alpha,sigY = 0.0,kM = 0.0,mM = 0.0):
        if (matPhysLaw=="elastic"):
            return ElasticMaterial(self,stressState,e,nu,alpha,sigY,kM,mM)
```

And the following Child Class:

```
class ElasticMaterial(Material):
    def __init__(self,StressState,e,nu,alpha,sigY=0.0,kM=0.0,mM=0.0):
        #Material.__init__(self,StressState,e,nu,alpha,sigY=0.0,kM=0.0,mM=0.0)
        self.StressState = StressState
        if self.StressState=='threed':
            self.lv=6  #lv is length of stress and strain vectors
        else:
            self.lv=4
        self.e = e
        self.nu = nu
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.sigY = sigY
        self.kM = kM
        self.mM = mM
```

I am trying to create the child class from the base class itself and I am calling the `newMaterial()` method as below:

```
m2 = Material.newMaterial('elastic','threed',10e6,0.2,1e7)
```

But, I am getting an error as `newMaterial() is missing 1 positional argument: alpha`.
I want an explanation as to why I am getting this error and how can I rectify it?

Comment: Just do what it tell you to do. Note that there is no `self` here.

Comment: You seems to have a huge confusion between (analogy from other languages) static methods and non-static methods. Constructors are non-static, the `newMaterial` method (as in the way you call it) is static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're calling `Material.newMaterial(...)` directly, `self` is not bound, so you're missing a mandatory argument. (You're trying to call `newMaterial` with `self='elastic'`, etc.)

Either remove the parameter and make it a [`@staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod):

```
class Material(object):

    @staticmethod
    def newMaterial(matPhysLaw, stressState, e, nu, alpha, sigY=0.0, kM=0.0, mM=0.0):
        if matPhysLaw == "elastic":
            # But here you don't need the `self` parameter for instantiation
            return ElasticMaterial(stressState, e, nu, alpha, sigY, kM, mM)
```

Or use a [`@classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) decorator if you need to keep a reference to the class:

```
class Material(object):

    @classmethod
    def newMaterial(cls, matPhysLaw, stressState, e, nu, alpha, sigY=0.0, kM=0.0, mM=0.0):
        if (matPhysLaw=="elastic"):
            return ElasticMaterial(stressState, e, nu, alpha, sigY, kM, mM)
    # Do something with `cls`...
```